# Can moderators see ninja edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderators

Suppose:

- Someone flags a post for good reason based on the content of the post
- No one posts a comment on the post
- Within the grace period, the OP changes the post so it no longer has the problematic content

At that point, it's a ninja edit; normal users (even 10k+ or 20k+) can't see the original version of the post.

(Or really, even if someone doesn't flag the post but the moderator has reason to investigate it at some stage.)

Can a moderator see that a ninja edit occurred, and see the original version of the post?

Comment: Are you talking about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40992330/revisions)? We can ask the mod [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34435532#34435532)

Comment: Sadly Nope, Moderators can't see ninja edits. As an aside, I've got 3 such flags declined (before the retract your flags feature)

Comment: Thanks for finding that earlier question, folks. That's what I get for using the wrong search terms. :-) I'll leave this as a pointer for someone searching on "ninja edit" in the future and not thinking of "grace period."